# Static pointer and operator new

Tags: c++

```
class X {
public:
    X(int i) : num(i){}
    int num;
};

void f(int i){

    static X* px1 = new X(i);
    X* px2 = new X(i);
    cout<<px1->num;
    cout<<px2->num<<' ';

};

void main(){
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++) 
        f(i);
}
```

This code will output `00 01 02 03 04`, but I don't quite understand why static pointer `px1` can't change its value using `operator new`.

Also, this code has memory leakage problem. Can I use `delete` with `px1`? Will using `delete` on both pointers solve memory leakage problem?

Comment: Not using `new` will solve the memory leak problem with a lot less code.

Comment: A word of caution. Since px1 is declared static if `px1` is deleted at the end of `f()`. The next time `f()` is called `px1` will be a dangling pointer. To fix this issue you would need to put `px1 = new X(i);` on a seperate line from the declaration of `px1`.

Comment: You _can_ use `delete px1`, but that's not the right question. The real problem is, "when should I call `delete px1`". There's no good moment.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes As written, there is no memory leak problem.  There is exactly one allocation, regardless of how often he calls the function.  (Not using dynamic allocation is probably a better solution anyway, but it does introduce an order of destructor problem the the code as written doesn't have.)

Comment: @JamesKanze The second line in the function allocates a new object each time the function is called.

Comment: @Charlie that's... wrong. The pointer has static storage duration, i.e., lasts until the program ends. The object created with new has dynamic storage duration, i.e., lasts until the destructor is invoked (`delete` is the obvious way of doing it). Since the destructor is never invoked, both the pointer and the object it points to last until the end of the program. No dangling pointer.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes  I agree with what you said.  My caution was if he decided to add code to delete px1...  per his question "Can I use delete with px1?"

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Yup.  I only looked at the part the question seemed to be about.  `px2` should definitely be a value, not a pointer.  (About the only case I could see using a pointer here would be if it were a `Base*`, and the initializer expression were a ternary operator allocated either a `Derived1` or a `Derived2`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because static locals are initialized only once when control first passes through the initialization code. So although you call the function multiple times the following line:

```
static X* px1 = new X(i);
```

will only be executed in the very first call (with `i` being zero) and the variable will persist its value between the function calls.

Yes, you can `delete` `px1` but you'd better set it to null afterwards to avoid double-free and undefined behavior. You also have leaks with objects pointed to by `px2` - you have to take care of those objects too.

Answer (score 4):

> but I don't quite understand why static pointer px1 can't change its
>   value using operator new

Static locals are initialized the first time they are called, and only the first time

> Will using delete on both pointers solve memory leakage problem?

Yes

As a better practice you should use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers and `delete` in this case. It does the `delete` for you automatically, so you won't leak.

Additionally neither of your allocations needs to be allocating on the heap. Normally you only use `new` if you want an object to persist outside of the scope it's created in. In this case, you don't need it to so you could just write:

```
static X x1(i);
X x2(i);
cout<<x1.num;
cout<<x2.num<<' ';
```

Comment: As an even better practice, you should just use `static X px1(i);`

Comment: Ya there is no reason to be `new`ing anything. I guess I'll add that.

Comment: Replace `X* x2(i);` with `X x2(i);` :-)

Comment: @Dave The way you've formulated the reason for not using `new` could be considered ambiguous.  The reason for using `static` is so that the variable will persist between calls to the function; i.e. beyond the end of scope.

Comment: @JamesKanze admittedly `new` also has other purposes. But, why is it ambiguous that 2 things in have overlapping purposes?

Comment: @Dave Ambiguous may not be the right word, but in this case, there _is_ an explicit desire for the lifetime to extend beyond end of scope, and I fear that an unwitting programmer could interpret your statement about `new` as meaning that it is appropriate here.